# Local Push Notification ios

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

If I wanted to send a push notification after my app wasn't opened in a week saying to come back and play, do I need to get the user's permission to send them this local push notification?

Comment: yes,  you do need to request permission to send notifications

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8, you need to ask the user permission to schedule the **Local Notification**. It's not required before iOS 8.

One more thing, you have to know the difference between **Push Notification** and **Local Notification**. It will confuse people when you describe your problem. Push Notification is sent from the **APNs** server. And local notification is scheduled from you applications.

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use **[Local notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)**. What you need to do is schedule a local notification after a week once user open the application. Everytime you schedule a notification cancel all earlier notification.

To cancel all notification use :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

To schedule a notification use :

```
  UILocalNotification* n1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    n1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 60];
    n1.alertBody = @"one";
    UILocalNotification* n2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    n2.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 90];
    n2.alertBody = @"two";
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: n2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to register for local notification in iOS 8 only.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be correct to add an else clause that registers the user if they are not an IOS 8? such as: if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
} else {  [application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]]; }

Comment: @Xsv23 Yes you are absolutely correct. In iOS 7 or less, you need to register directly.